# enconde text with special characters

Tags: c#, url, encoding

I have one text that have '%' and I would like to use in link, but I receice a error,(bad request)

Sample:

```
@{

var title = "less than 1% ."; ///this I would like to pass in url

var url = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(title); //I try it, but not work!

}

<a href="/cidades/cidade/Categoria/@url">go to city</a>
```

I use this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Categoria",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/categoria/{nome}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Cidades", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

`HtmlEncode` is for translating special charaters to *HTML*.  Use `UrlEncode` to encode special characters into a valid *URL*:

```
var url = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(title);
```

Comment: I try it before. Not work! I think the problem is the '%' that have in text

Comment: What does "Not work" mean - are you decoding it on the other end?  What URL do you get as a result?

Comment: When I use HttpUtility.UrlEncode(title); the error is 404 and the url that produce is "cidades/cidade/Categoria/less+than+1%25+."
So, I have this page and work normaly. The problem is when text come with '%'

Comment: Sounds more like the path is incorrect and not an issue with the encoding.

Comment: 404 means the page is not found.  Is there a handler or route that is supposed to process that URL?

Comment: hi, I create one route like "{controller}/{action}/categoria/{nome}".. Is necessary to use some validation in route?

Comment: Some web servers might see an uppercase C in Categoria as a different path from .../categoria/... - But that is just be a shot in the dark from my point of view.